# iMac will not boot OS X after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, macosx

I installed Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X on my iMac, following [HowToGeek's tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/).

Whenever I boot, I get GRUB with the following options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced Options for Ubuntu
- Mac OS X 32-bit
- Mac OS X 64-bit

Ubuntu boots fine, however Mac OS X does not. I think this is a GRUB problem. Any ideas?

This is the screen I get when booting from GRUB:
[image: Screengrab]

Comment: Default grub setups won't boot OS X properly. Hold option at boot to get the mac bootloader back temporarily, then (re)install refind to your esp [make sure you're not just installing to the OS X partition or it won't work. Yosemite needs it on the esp for some reason.] and you'll be able to boot both OS's no issues. Alternatively, look into chainload booting OSX from grub. If you need a step by step, let me know and I'll add it in when I'm not mobile.

Comment: the only apple keyboard I have is bluetooth, So I tried holding alt on a pc keyboard plugged into the iMac and had no result. Also, the iMac is a good ten years old.